# How to handle one popup triggered from another popup?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am testing Selenium 2.29 with Firefox 8.0.1 (previously on 2.17 due to Modal dialog issue kept me at FF 11 as max version). I have a icon that when clicked triggers some javascript code. This JS code triggers a popup that I am able to handle using this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(""xpath_to_icon")).click;
```

`log("Alert text = " + getAlertText()); //log just outputs to the console`

`acceptAlert;`

The above code handles the trigger and acceptance of the first popup with no problem. The issue I have is clicking 'OK' on that first popup (which I must do for my test) triggers a second popup. So far I have not been successful in handling this second popup. I have tried variations of the following code with no luck:

```
acceptAlert;

driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

selenium.keyDownNative("32");
selenium.keyUpNative("32");

 Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
     // driver.findElement("").click();
     log("Alert2 text = " + getAlertText());
     acceptAlert();
     }
     });
     t.start();
```

Each time this error is thrown: org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present. Previously I would manually click the 'OK' button on the second popup but that is not possible anymore with 2.29.

Currently I only have one test case that has this specific issue but I would like to see if anyone else has encountered this & found a good way to handle it. Thank you.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what your problem is, but I think it is clicking an element in the first popup, that should open a second popup. I use PHP to drive Selenium. There you have to manually change to the correct (i)frame or window (in your case). I suspect it is the same with the [Java-client](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/NextSteps)

Answer (score 0):

Qrazi is right that if there are frames you have to code change the frame targeted, and new popups need to have focus switched to them. `selectFrame`, `selectPopup` and `selectWindow` is a good place to start.

Once you have switched focus, then you can automate clicking the 'OK' button. Don't forget to switch focus back at the end!

For frames the following code   puts frame focus at top of page. Once you are inside a frame you cannot see the parent frame(s) anymore.

```
Driver.getDriver().switchTo().defaultContent();
```